# Incrementing number in foreach PHP

Tags: php, foreach, numbers, increment

I want to fill the keys in array but the keys will be increment and when meets certain number, it will stop and repeat the first increment again.

I will give the code, so it'll be more understandable.

```
$start = 0004;
$end = 0150;
$trans = array();
for ($c = $start; $c <= $end; $c++) {
    $strpad = str_pad($c, 4, "000", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $trans[] = $strpad;
}

$numtable = 1062;
$newarray = array();  
foreach($trans as $value) {
    $newarray[$numtable] = $value;
    $numtable++;
}
var_dump($newarray);
// output
array(147) {
  [1062]=>
  string(4) "0004"
  [1063]=>
  string(4) "0005"
  [1064]=>
  string(4) "0006"
  [1065]=>
  string(4) "0007"
  [1066]=>
  string(4) "0008"
and so on....
// end output
```

Now, what I wanted was, when the increment number reach 1100, it will reset to 1000 and continue increment, and when it reaches 1100 again, it will reset to 1000 and continue again.

So, what i'm trying to do was this:

```
$numtable = 1062;
$newarray = array();  
foreach($trans as $value) {
    if($numtable==1101){
        $numtable = 1000;
    }
    $newarray[$numtable] = $value;
    $numtable++;
}
var_dump($newarray);
// output


  array(101) {
  [1062]=>
  string(4) "0105"
  [1063]=>
  string(4) "0106"
  [1064]=>
  string(4) "0107"
  [1065]=>
  string(4) "0108"
and so on.. continue to...
  string(4) "0148"
  [1005]=>
  string(4) "0149"
  [1006]=>
  string(4) "0150"
  [1007]=>
  string(4) "0050"
  [1008]=>
  string(4) "0051"
And so on...
```

My question is:
I'm pretty sure my code with 2nd code was right.
But, why the array values start with 0105 not 0004?
And when the value reach 0150, It still continue looping start to 0050?

Does my code have some bugs?

Comment: var_Dump the first array, and check what's in that array?

Comment: As you can saw in my post above, the first array have array(147) {
  [1062]=>
  string(4) "0004"
  [1063]=>
  string(4) "0005"

Comment: I can't see* anything of your array $trans...

Answer (score 0):

For counting issues like this, just use a [modulus operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
$numtable = 1062;
$numtable_min = 1000;
$numtable_max = 1101;
$newarray = array();  
foreach($trans as $value) {
    $numtable = $numtable % $numtable_max == 0 ? $numtable_min : $numtable;
    $newarray[$numtable] = $value;
    $numtable++;
}
```

All of the magic is in here:

```
$numtable = $numtable % $numtable_max == 0 ? $numtable_min : $numtable;
```

And another way to understand it is to replace the variables with real values like this:

```
$numtable = 1062 % 1101 == 0 ? 1000 : 1062;
```

So the way that ternary line reads is this; assign `$numtable` a value based on:

- `1062 % 1101 == 0` That will only reach `0` if the incremented value of `1062` gets to `1101`.
- If that happens, set that value to `1000`.
- If not, set that value to what the `1062` is.

The simples way to understand the magic of a modulus operator is to think of `%` as calculating the remainder of the number on the left of the `%` to the number on the right.

So `1062` divided by `1101` would have a remainder of `0.96457765667`. But `1101` divided by `1101` has no remainder; aka: `0`. So shove that into a ternary & you have one nice solid line of logic for cases like this.

Comment: Hi JakeGloud, thanks for your answer here. Modulus operator is beyond my think, so it's great that this method here (modulus) could be use to counting or make break line. After i tried that. $trans array at first i've counted (using count) were 147. After, i used your method, it were down to 100. And the array start with key 1062 and value 0104. My question is why the value was 0104 not 0004? What i'm trying to get is the key 1062 and the value start with 0004. And when the key reach 1100, it will be reset and start from 1000, but the values continue.

Comment: @JakeGloud, I'm pretty sure, that no anything else that affect the array of trans. The value start 0104 if i apply the modulus or the if break.